# How to substitute value of one variable from an equation in another to get the desired result?

Tags: algebra

I have this equation

```
{(Sqrt[m] ((e + m)/m)^(3/2) (e^2 p0 + m^2 p0 + 2 m (p1^2 + p2^2 + p3^2) + 
p0 (p1^2 + p2^2 + p3^2) + 2 e (m p0 + p1^2 + p2^2 + p3^2)))/(e + m)^(5/2)}
```

I want to use

```
p^2=p1^2+p2^2+p3^2;
```

and

```
e^2=p^2+m^2
```

to simplify the 1st equation. How can I replace the variables and simplify the equation? I have more equations to simply in this way, what is the most general way to approach it?

Comment: Perhaps [`Eliminate`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Eliminate.html)?

Comment: Well I cant equate my equation with 0, So, I don't think it will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
expr={(Sqrt[m] ((e + m)/m)^(3/2) (e^2 p0 + m^2 p0 + 2 m (p1^2 + p2^2 + p3^2) +
p0 (p1^2 + p2^2 + p3^2) + 2 e (m p0 + p1^2 + p2^2 + p3^2)))/(e + m)^(5/2)}

expr /. {p1 -> Sqrt[p^2 - p2^2 - p3^2] ,e -> Sqrt[p^2 + m^2]} // Simplify
(*{(2 Sqrt[m] ((m + Sqrt[m^2 + p^2])/m)^(3/2) (m^2 p0 + p^2 (Sqrt[m^2 + p^2] + p0) + 
m (p^2 + Sqrt[m^2 + p^2] p0)))/(m + Sqrt[m^2 + p^2])^(5/2)}*)
```

Comment: Yeah, it does simply but only to an extent. Why Simplify or even FullSimplify isn't able to cancel the sq. root terms? I would prefer more simplification.

Comment: The sqrt-terms depend on `m` and `p`, `e` is eliminated. What kind of simplification you're looking for?

Comment: I was hoping that the square root terms in the numerator and denominator would cancel.